# How to set the server-log location in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, logging, spring-logback

I recently started working in a Spring boot application. The application uses spring-logback for logging implementation.

The application is bundled as a war in different environments. However, the location of writing logs is different in each environment and is mentioned in a `logging.properties` file.

Therefore, I currently have to change the location before preparing the war every time.

How can I set the path of the logs in the Tomcat configuration so that the path is auto-picked for an environment.

Currently mu logback appender looks like this:

```
<appender name="FILE"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${logging.file}</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">

        <!-- daily rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>${logging.file}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>${log.file.size}</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <maxHistory>${log.file.history}</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>${logging.pattern.file}</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

All the properties here are picked from `logging.properties` file inside the `src/main/resources`

Answer (score 0):

spring-boot provides several `logging.*` settings that can be applied in application.properties, like:

```
logging.level.=DEBUG
logging.file=myfile.log
logging.path=d:/logs/
```

If you set logging.path, Spring Boot writes spring.log to the specified directory. Names can be an exact location or relative to the current directory.

Comment: Hi @Aman Garg, As mentioned the WAR needs to be independent for different environments. If I place this path in application.properties (which is the case currently), the WAR cannot be reused in different server without changing the path for each server.

Comment: @Saurabh, either the logs folder get created on each server. In such case its is not the issue. Or second is you want to create log files on a common server (or network path as it do not support http). In such case, you can also provide some identifier in the path like logging.path=logs\{some_other_application_property}

Comment: Hi Aman, You are right. The log folder gets created on each server but the location is different. For example on server A it can be C://logs while on server B it can be E:// logs. Hence I will have to change this path in `logging.file` in the application,properties for each environment.

Comment: Ohh for that Saurabh, you can use relative path instead of absolute path. Or you can use spring profiles for each server.